# Сложное приложение на одной windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как создать сложное приложение windows form с использованием только одной формы что бы наполнение формы нужными элементами зависело от выбранного пункта меню?

Answer (score 4):

Вопрос слишком общий, но я попробую на него ответить.

1) `TabControl`. Ты можешь заранее повесить элементы на каждый Tab, а затем управлять видимостью конкретных вкладок

2)Кинуть все элементы на форму, а потом в зависимости от выбора делать одни элементы видимыми, а другие нет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать UserControl (Пользовательский элемент управления).

1) Создайте (правой кнопкой на проекте > добавить > пользовательский элемент управления) столько сколько нужно UserControl-ов в проекте.

2) Наполните каждый элементы управления, как вам нужно. Вам будет доступен обычный Дизайнер или можно создавать всё кодом в конструкторе.

3) Бросьте на вашу форму Panel.
Когда нужно создавайте UserControl и встраивайте в панель.

```
void mybutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var oldcontrol = panel1.Controls.SingleOrDefault();
    panel1.Controls.Clear();
    oldcontrol?.Dispose();

    var ucontrol = new MyUserControl();                    
    panel1.Controls.Add(ucontrol1);
    ucontrol.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; 
}
```